# Registering - Unregistering Device from Android GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add push notification feature to my application, but i have strange problems.

In my first try, i got regId for device; but after that device trying to unregister it self from GCM; actually it succeeed becuase i lost regId but not i couldn't get it again.

In LogCat i see these lines.

```
07-12 08:40:25.615: V/GCMRegistrar(10648): Registering receiver
07-12 08:40:25.620: D/GCMRegistrar(10648): resetting backoff for PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:25.635: V/GCMRegistrar(10648): Unregistering app PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:28.570: D/GCMRegistrar(10648): resetting backoff for PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:28.570: V/GCMRegistrar(10648): Unregistering app PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:29.125: D/GCMRegistrar(10648): resetting backoff for PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:29.130: V/GCMRegistrar(10648): Unregistering app PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:39.655: D/GCMRegistrar(10648): resetting backoff for PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:39.660: V/GCMRegistrar(10648): Unregistering app PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:40.605: D/GCMRegistrar(10648): resetting backoff for PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:40.605: V/GCMRegistrar(10648): Unregistering app PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:41.350: D/GCMRegistrar(10648): resetting backoff for PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:41.350: V/GCMRegistrar(10648): Unregistering app PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:43.255: D/GCMRegistrar(10648): resetting backoff for PACKAGENAME
07-12 08:40:43.255: V/GCMRegistrar(10648): Unregistering app PACKAGENAME
```

I tried to implement GCM Demo Application's code to my application, so here is the code.

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

if (regId.equals("")) {
    // Automatically registers application on
    // startup.
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    // Device is already registered on GCM, needs to
    // check if it is
    // registered on our server as well.
    if (!GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
        // Try to register again, but not in the UI
        // thread.
        // It's also necessary to cancel the thread
        // onDestroy(),
        // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a
        // raw thread.
        final Context context = this;
        mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem, its all of my fault and sillyness.

I was added `GCMRegistrar.unregister ()` code to Evaluations; so every step on debug cause to reevaluate this code and call unregister.

I don't want to delete it, may be there is someone like me ;)

Comment: how to check whether device is registered or not in GCM./

Comment: final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this); this line gives you the answer. If it is empty device is not registered, otherwise registered.